# Collapse a key-value file with Bash command lines

Tags: bash

I have a file like:

```
foobar Me
baz    I
baz    love
foobar too.
baz    you.
```

I would like to collapse it using the first column as a key, and the second column as accumulated information.  In the previous example, the output would be:

```
baz    I love you.
foobar Me too.
```

(the second column would be joined by spaces or tabs)

I know I can do it in AWK, Python, Perl, etc. but I would like to do it with plain Bash commands.

Comment: Do you want one single built-in bash command (which does not exist), or do you want some bash code which uses only built-ins (what have you already tried?), or do you want a reference to a particular tool (e.g. similar to `join`)?

Comment: @MartinNyolt Hopefully, I was expecting a series of clever commands, including stuff like `join`, `sort` or `paste`.  I tried `awk '{a[$1] = a[$1] " " $2}END{for (v in a) print v "\t" a[v]}' file`.  Well, maybe I asked something impossible?

Comment: yeah, but why though? Why would you want to use bash over an actual text parsing language? join sort and paste are all also not bash.

Comment: My aim was to share the code with a person that does not how to code, and is learning Linux.  `join`, `sort`, and the like are not Bash, but they are heavily used (at least in bio-informatics, where I teach).

Comment: Transforming your AWK code to bash should be straight forward. Bash supports associative arrays and you can extract the two parts using ${line%} and ${line#} or similar. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yup, I have `declare -A a; while read -r line; do b=(${line//"\t"/ }); a[${b[0]}]=${a[${b[0]}]}" "${b[1]}; done < file; for i in "${!a[@]}"; do echo $i ${a[$i]}; done`.  I was hoping not to write something that complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just bash, read the file in a `while` loop, and accumulate the values in an associative array.

```
$ declare -A values
$ while read -r key val; do values["$key"]+="$val "; done < file
$ for key in "${!values[@]}"; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "${values[$key]}"; done
baz     I love you.
foobar  Me too.
```

Note that the order of the array keys is **indeterminate**. It is just by chance that the output is baz then foobar. If you need the output to have a particular order, you'll need a bit more code.